# Multiple Comment Forms in a single page

Tags: comments

I would like to make a "Comment" section on every of my page on my wordpress website.

So if you head to http://www.lolcounter.com/champions/lee-sin,
You can see on top of the page the "General Counter Tips" with bellow it, 4 comments.

There is more comment then this and you can see it if you click the "View More Counter Tips" and you can post a tip if you click "Submit a Counter Tip".

My question is, how do I make something similar to this with wordpress ?
I actually have multiple page that I want to add this feature on them, but all of them need to have different comments.

Do I make this with a custom post type ? Or I add everything into a table into my DB? or is there any other way?

Thanks for any help :) !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the `number` argument to `get_comments()` to retrieve only a specific number of comments. They will, by standard, be sorted descending, so you get the latest comments first.

As WordPress automatically seperates comments for each post, you will not have to worry about mixing comments up. This seems to be the easiest way for me.

**Multiple comment forms per page -> Passing Post ID**

If you need multiple comment forms on one page, you can use several `get_comments()`, but you have to pass the post IDs for the comments you want to show.

Example:

```
$postID = 4;
$number_of_posts = 6;

$args = array(
    'number' => $number_of_posts,
    'post_id' => $postID
);

$your_comments = get_comments($args);
```

**Make it dynamic -> Extract IDs from post_meta and loop over them**

Post IDs are saved comma-seperated in a field called `commentIDs`, code would be placed in a `single.php` for example.

```
// get IDs for current post
$cmmntIDs = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'commentIDs', true);
$theIDs = explode(',', $cmmntIDs);

// get comments for each ID you defined
foreach($theIDs as $theID) {
    $args = array(
        'number' => $number_of_posts,
        'post_id' => $theID
    );
    $comments = get_comments($args);

    // basic output from the Codex Page on get_comments()
    foreach($comments as $comment) {
        echo($comment->comment_author);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, but if I want multiple comment form on the same page, there will be conflict right ?

Comment: Not really. You just have to pass the `post ID` to `get_comments()` then. It´s your choice where you get those from (fixed or dynamic).

Comment: I see.
I want to make this into a page-teamplate to use on page (not posts). So I would have multiple get_comments() with different IDs. If I use this page-template on another page, this will give me the same comments, or I have to send different ids to the different pages?

Comment: You would have to send different IDs, yes. But you could use `post_meta` (works for pages too, I think) to pass the IDs in an easy way. Or you find a way to automate which IDs are to be chosen.

Comment: Alright, well is there a way to send IDs like you say, but have multiple type of comment form ? So I would have my comment form 1, with id 1, and type A, and a comment form 2, with id 2 and type B

Comment: See the updated code.